# If someone tells you to trespass, can you trespass?

Tags: united-states

Sometimes I watch encounters where a person tauntingly but clearly telling another person to come here,[here as in his own property], or come here if you are a man, etc etc..

Is it legal to go on to his property as you have his permission?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although that strictly speaking that would depend on the precise, statutory definition of trespass. For instance, see [MCL 750.552(1)(a)](http://www.legislature.mi.gov/(S(nhnony2ekyytiiuf2ghrcwpq))/mileg.aspx?page=getObject&objectName=mcl-750-552):

> a person shall not do any of the following:
>
> (a) Enter the lands or premises of another **without lawful authority**
>   after having been forbidden to do so by the owner or occupant or the
>   agent of the owner or occupant.

(emphasis added)

The scenario you describe amounts to granting permission (i.e., lawful authority) to enter the challenging owner's/occupant's premises. Notice that the statute does not outlaw entry into property where invitation thereto is rhetorical or confrontational.

Comment: I get the rhetorical part, but in what sense is "confrontational", thanks alot btw

Comment: @AhmedTaha I would assume something like "Get over here, so I can properly kick your ass" would be a confrontational invitation.  I would decline such invitations.

Comment: Lol, Alright, thanks alot man, appreciate it.

Comment: The kind of statement described in the question sounds like a "dare" or a taunt, or a threat, or a sarcastic statement that means the opposite of its literal meaning, not a grant of permission to enter onto the property or to assault someone once you got there. The OP engages in an insufficiently sophisticated analysis of the actual meaning of the language used when it concludes summarily that these kinds of statements actually grant permission to trespass or enter. An "invitation" to enter conditioned on self-help punishment from the person extending the "invitation" isn't really permission.

Comment: @ohwilleke A court is supposed to look into the ordinary, plain meaning of words, not to engage in metaphysical speculation of messages arising between the occupant and the interlocutor. An occupant's indication "*come here*" certainly constitutes permission even if the indication is foreseeably intended to involve or escalate confrontation. If anything, a competent judge/juror would lower its expectations that in a heated setting the pseudo-trespasser will identify such indications as "sarcasm".

Comment: "A court is supposed to look into the ordinary, plain meaning of words," only when interpreting statutes and contracts without parole evidence. Absolutely not when evaluating the meaning of a conversation between two people. A court that did that would verge on committing reversible error when the court gave the words meaning contrary to the context because of their plain meaning in the absence of context. That maxim, at a minimum would be an error of law in this context.

Comment: @ohwilleke Convicting for trespass is out of reach unless occupant made it reasonably clear that his direction did not amount to authorizating the interlocutor (example: "*come here and I'll get you arrested*"). By contrast, directions such as "*come here if you're a man*" or unconditional ones as in "*come here if you're a man*" forfeit an occupant's allegations that entry was "not authorized": Luring someone into doing an act is inconsistent with accusing that individual for having done so on that occasion. A context of confrontation does not imply a direction was rhetorical or sarcastic.

Comment: "come here if you're a man" is just another way of saying, if you come here I'll punish you. This is not permission or authorization. It is urging him to break the law.

Comment: @ohwilleke "*'come here if you're a man' is just another way of saying, if you come here I'll punish you*". That is your subjective interpretation and, albeit a plausible one, at that point a conviction *for trespass* is ruled out because of the language "*come here*". "*It is urging him to break the law*". By urging him, the occupant cannot later deny that he *willfully and explicitly* encouraged the individual to enter the property. Thus, the occupant cannot reasonably allege later on that that was not a permission.